# Deleted an Azure App Service slot and now I can't get the original hostname back when trying to recreate it

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

I deleted a slot because it was giving us trouble. Now when I try to recreate it with the same name it appends some random numbers and letters to the end (i.e. staging > staging3c01). Is there any way I can get the original name back? Otherwise I have to go and reset a bunch of settings to point to the new hostname.

Comment: Do you mean you had a Deployment Slot on a Web App named "Staging". Or was the Web App itself named "Staging"?

Comment: Deployment slot named "Staging"

Comment: I could not reproduced your issue, it works fine on my side. I recommend you to try again.

Comment: I have not been able to reproduce the issue on any of my other app services. If it helps, the app service giving me troubles is also hosted under an ASE

Answer (score 0):

Faced with the same. This is bug in the App Service: sometimes records for old slot remains in the internal database (funny that bug still there after almost 4 years). You should open support ticket to resolve it. You can use reference ticket id #2202160050002784.